# Data Migration Tool with splitted database

Tags: magento2, database, data-migration-tool

I would like to migrate data from my Magento 1 website to the new Magento 2 one.

In the Magento 2 instance, I've splitted the database for performance reasons (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master.html), so I've got more than one destination databases.

Is it possible to use Data Migration Tool with a destination splitted database?

Answer (score 0):

It has just been announced that the split database will be deprecated from version 2.4.2.

Soon there will be recommendations for moving to a single database.

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Deprecation-of-split-database-functionality-in-Magento-Commerce/ba-p/465187